# Correctly parametrize event handler for input type file and material ui Button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to build a form, which for a given set of options (stored in an array in component's state) gives you the possibility to upload a file and add a note for each option. The forms are custom, but the elements are from material UI.

The code looks something like this (simplified, stripped of other unneeded data).

```
public renderOptions() {
    const { mdFiles } = this.state
    return options.map((option, i) => 
        <FileUpload
            handleChange={(e) => {this.handleFileInputChange(e, i)}}
        />
        <TextField
            key={`option-${i}`}
            name={option.name} */
            type="text"
            fullWidth
            label={item}
            placeholder={`Edit ${item}`}
            value={option.note || option.originalNote}
            onChange={(e) => this.handleChangeFileName(e, i)}
         />

    )
}
```

I want to parametrize the event handlers, so that, besides the event, an index is passed, so I have a connection between the note and/or uploaded file and the option.

Changing the note works as expected, but the problem is in the `FileUpload` component.

It contains a simple `input` of type `file`, but the input is hidden and only the button is visible - example is taken from the official material ui docs (https://material-ui.com/demos/buttons/ -> https://codesandbox.io/s/qzr18l41ow)

The code looks like this

```
class FileUpload extends React.Component<Props, {}> {
    public render() {
        return (
            <FileWrapper>
                <input
                    accept={fileType}
                    id="file-upload"
                    type="file"
                    onChange={handleChange}
                />
                <label htmlFor="file-upload" id="file-upload">
                    <Button
                        variant="contained"
                        component="span"
                    >
                        Upload
                    </Button>
                </label>
            </FileWrapper>
        )
    }
}
```

The problem is that in `handleFileInputChange` method the second argument (index) is always zero - so for whatever option I upload the file for - it is always attached to the first option.
Now, when I strip the button (remove it) and just work with the input alone - everything works as expected.
Seems the button and the label are disabling the proper connection with the passed event handler.

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem...

Each file input has to have a unique id. In your code they all have id="file-upload". This is why all of the buttons trigger the onchange handler of the first input.

Here's a modified version where the ID set dynamically.

```js
class FileUpload extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { id, handleChange } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <input id={id} type="file" onChange={handleChange} />
        <label htmlFor={id} id={`${id}`}>
          <Button variant="contained" component="span">
            Upload
          </Button>
        </label>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Live example:**

[image: Edit Material demo]